# How to increase maxUrlLength in OWIN self host?

Tags: url, owin, maxlength, katana

It's possible to increase max request length in .NET 4 using `maxUrlLength` attribute. Is there a way to do it in OWIN self host?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These Http.Sys registry settings affect Katana self-host: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/820129